# Selenium2 Java - Check if value on page is greater than X

Tags: java, html, selenium

I've got a  tag on a web page which will contain a value supplied by Python (an integer which comes from an AWS Athena query - it'll be 0 if the query fails).

I want to make an assertion that the value is greater than 0. How can I do this? The HTML for this part of the page will be

```
<h1>Total: 5</h1>
```

I've currently got

```
assert driver.getPageSource().contains("Total");
```

but want to check that the value is greater than 0 too.

edit:
Added

```
assert !driver.getPageSource().contains("Total: 0");
```

Which seems to work. Any better ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assert that the `<h1>` tag doesn't contains any text as **0** you can simplyfy your query as follows :

```
assert !driver.findElement(By.tagName("h1")).getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("0");
```